# Mean and standard deviation with multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple dataframes having the same columns and the same number of observations:
For example

```
d1 = {'ID': ['A','B','C','D'], 'Amount': 
    [1,2,3,4]}
df1 =pd.DataFrame(data=d1)

d2 = {'ID': ['A','B','C','D'], 'Amount': 
    [6,0,1,5]}
df2 =pd.DataFrame(data=d2)

d3 = {'ID': ['A','B','C','D'], 'Amount': 
    [8,1,2,3]}
df3 =pd.DataFrame(data=d3)
```

I need to drop one column (D) and its corresponding value in each of the dataframes and then, for each variable, calculating the mean and standard deviation.
The expected output should be

```
  avg   std
A   5    ...
B  ...   ...
C  ...   ...
```

Generally, for one dataframe, I would use drop columns and then I would compute the average using mean() and the standard deviation std().
How can I do this in an easy and fast way with multiple dataframes? (I have at least 10 of them).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with remove `D` in [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) and aggregate by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with named aggregations:

```
df = (pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])
        .query('ID != "D"')
        .groupby('ID')
        .agg(avg=('Amount', 'mean'), std=('Amount', 'std')))
print (df)
    avg       std
ID               
A     5  3.605551
B     1  1.000000
C     2  1.000000
```

Or remove `D` in last step by [`DataFrame.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
df = (pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])
        .groupby('ID')
        .agg(avg=('Amount', 'mean'), std=('Amount', 'std'))
        .drop('D'))
```

Comment: @LdM - Simpliest is `.drop(['D', 'A', 'C'])` for remove `A, C, D` rows

Answer (score 3):

You can use pivot_table as well:

```
import numpy as np

pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]).pivot_table(index='ID', aggfunc=[np.mean, np.std]).drop('D')
```